# I made a simple hello world ,, kernel ''. It doesn't print anything. What did I do wrong?

Tags: assembly, x86, g++, osdev, grub

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rnA6wpF0o4 in order to write a very very basic hello world after boot, as it seems very complete on the next episodes. My problem is that I cannot see what I've done wrong as I verified twice if my code is exactly the same as in the video. It passes grub and then it is just black screen instead of printing the message.
I have tried connecting to the forum in the description to ask questions but it is in German and forum page does not load.

So here are the sources:
kernel.cpp

```
void printf(char *str)
{
    unsigned short* VideoMemory = (unsigned short*)0xb8000;
    for(int i=0; str[i]!= '\0'; ++i)
        VideoMemory[i]=(VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
}

extern "C" void kernelMain(void* multiboot_structure, unsigned int magicnumber)
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    while(1);
}
```

linker.ld

```
ENTRY(loader)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:i386)

SECTIONS 
{
    . = 0x0100000;
    
    .text :
    {
     *(.multiboot)
     *(.text*)
     *(.rodata)
    }
    
    .data :
    {
        start_ctors = .;
        KEEP(*( .init_array ));
        KEEP(*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY( .init_array.* )));
        end_ctors = .;
        
        *(.data)
    }
    
    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }
    
    /DISCARD/ : 
    {
        *(.fini_array*)
        *(.comment)
    }
}
```

loader.s

```
.set MAGIC, 0x1badb002
.set FLAGS, (1<<0 | 1<<1)
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
    .long MAGIC
    .long FLAGS
    .long CHECKSUM


.section .text
.extern kernelMain
.global loader

loader:
    mov $kernel_stack, %esp
    push %eax
    push %ebx
    call kernelMain
    
_stop:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp _stop
    
.section .bss
.space 2*1024*1024 # 2 MiB
kernel_stack:
```

and Makefile

```
GPPPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<
    
mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects) 

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

in /boot/grub/grub.cfg, i added:

```
menuentry 'My kernel' {
    multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin
    boot
}
```

Thanks in advance and have my excuses if I didn't write my question clear enough.

Comment: One problem is the code assumes that the foreground and background color on the screen is something viewable (it could be black on black. You could make sure it is visible with something like white on black `VideoMemory[i]=(0x0F << 8) | str[i];` and since video memory is memory mapped IO the pointer to video memory should be volatile. `volatile unsigned short* VideoMemory = (unsigned short*)0xb8000;`

Comment: @MichaelPetch, I have tried these changes but it still does not work. I have understood your point, corrected it into the program, but I think my program still has some error I cannot see, it may be in the other sources which I do not understand so clearly. ( I can only say that I know C at some decent level )

Comment: Upd: I have tried to load my kernel into another laptop and it shows that it does not find mykernel.bin in /boot/mykernel.bin despite the file being there. I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: output when opening kernel from grub:
error file /boot/mykernel.bin not found, error you need to load the kernel first.

command "ls /boot/" shows mykernel.bin is there.

Comment: @SofroneaGeorgian You should consider write an answer for this to put the solutions you found in comments and added to the Question.

Comment: @SofroneaGeorgian I am also facing the same error. Can you please let me know how you fixed it?

Comment: @Supersic if I recall correctly, one problem was the FF00 part. Try using 0F00, as it could be black text on black background, as an upper comment says, and also mark it volatile. If it helps, check out github.com/georgiansof/atestat---Operating-System , I have it versioned, go to BlockOS/src/v1(printf) and if you encounter any more problems, you can check the code of the version you are working on. Also try using VirtualBox because you need MBR partition type to boot. It is mandatory, because if you run gpt it uses another mechanism and your code is not valid, showing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: It only works under MBR/CSM legacy configurations and I found out that all the computers which I tried were UEFI/GPT. Now I do not know how to make it compatible for UEFI/GPT, but if I cannot that's fine, I could not find anything on the internet. It works under Virtualbox, after replacing 0F00 instead of FF00 as it was also writing black on black. (check comments for more details)